# javascript is not working for chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am a beginner to chrome extension development. My problem is nothing but the alert box is not coming and I think the javascript block itself is not working when I run the application as an extension. But it is working fine in firefox and chrome browser properly when I run the HTML file alone. can anyone help me?

manifest code

```
{
"name": "Intruder",
"description": "Monitoring all your activities.",
"version": "1.1",
"permissions": [
"tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
],
"browser_action": {
  "default_title": "Watching you",
  "default_icon": "badge.png",
  "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"manifest_version": 2
}
```

HTML code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Intruders World</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="jscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="background-color: whitesmoke">
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.forms["myForm"]["username"].value;
            if (x == "") {
                window.alert("u have to enter it");
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "box must be filled!";
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
    <p id="demo">Password Locker</p>
    <form name="myForm">
        Media Name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="medianame">
        <br>
        User name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="username">
        <br>
        Type Password:<br>
        <input type="password" name="passwd">
        <br>
        Re-type Password
        <input type="password" name="repasswd">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" onclick="myFunction()">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

css code

```
input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #404040;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 22px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
```

Comment: TL;DR - extract all inline scripts (including onclick attributes) to a separate file.

Comment: when I separate the script code to another file, is there anything I do in manifest file?

Comment: No. You declare it the same as `<script src="jscript.js"></script>`

Comment: I tried it. but again it is not working

Comment: Well, obviously you didn't do it right, but I can't help if I don't see the new code.